# Pandas dataframe: No numeric data to plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a table stored in a database in `MySQL`.

I fetched the results using MySQL connector and copied it to DataFrame. There are no problems till that.

Now as I'm taking the results from MySQL, they are in the form of strings, so I've converted the `strings` to `int` for the values of `CONFIRMED_CASES`, and leave the `STATE_NAME` as `str`.
Now I want to plot it in a bar graph, with Numeric data as CONFIRMED_CASES and state names as STATE_NAME but it shows me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\intel\Desktop\Covid Tracker\get_sql_data.py", line 66, in <module>
    fd.get_graph()
  File "c:\Users\intel\Desktop\Covid Tracker\get_sql_data.py", line 59, in get_graph
    ax = df.plot(y='STATE_NAME', x='CONFIRMED_CASES',
    ...
    raise TypeError("no numeric data to plot")
TypeError: no numeric data to plot
```

**Here's my code:**

```
from operator import index
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import mysql.connector
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="abhay",
    password="1234",
    database="covid_db"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()


class fetch_data():
    def __init__(self):
        ...

    def get_data(self, cmd):
        ...

    def get_graph(self):
        mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
            host="localhost",
            user="abhay",
            password="1234",
            database="covid_db"
        )

        mycursor = mydb.cursor(buffered=True)

        mycursor.execute(
            "select CONFIRMED_CASES from india;")
        query = mycursor.fetchall()

        # the data was like 10,000 so I removed the ',' and converted it to int
        query = [int(x[0].replace(',', '')) for x in query]
        print(query)

        query2 = mycursor.execute(
            "select STATE_NAME from india;")
        query2 = mycursor.fetchall()

        # this is the query for state name and i kept it as str only...
        query2 = [x[0] for x in query2]
        print(query2)

        df = pd.DataFrame({
            'CONFIRMED_CASES': [query],
            'STATE_NAME': [query2],
        })

        # it gives me the error here...
        ax = df.plot(y='STATE_NAME', x='CONFIRMED_CASES',
                kind='bar')

        ax.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='y')
        plt.show()


fd = fetch_data()
fd.get_graph()
```

I don't know why there is no numeric value. I set it to `int`, but still...

Comment: What does your data look like? Can you provide a snippet of your dataframe `df`?

Comment: No it's solved. Thanks for asking @busybear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heyy guys,
It's solved.
I used `query.values` and it worked...

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for converting data to integer before plotting graph.

```
df['CONFIRMED_CASES'] = df['CONFIRMED_CASES'].astype('int64')
```

Comment: No. It's still showing the same error :( I tried both of ur answers, but still the same...

Answer (score 0):

Your dataframe is defined using lists of a list. `query` and `query2` are lists already. Define your dataframe as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
            'CONFIRMED_CASES': query, # no brackets
            'STATE_NAME': query2,     # no brackets
        })
```

Comment: No. It's still showing the same error :(
I tried both the answers, but still...